# Discovery JavaScript execution path and files in Browser Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, developer-tools

I'm sure this must be a burden to other people too...

Say I am debugging a website, and there is an element on the site that when clicked calls a particular function; for example:

```
<img src="foo.png" onclick="javascript:Bar();" />
```

But I have no idea where `Bar` is declared in terms of the file structure. It could be coming from an external source or could be in the website solution.

Are there any tools that can be added into the browser (i.e. a FireFox extension) that can assist with this?

*I'd sort of like something that when I click something that fires some javascript, breaks the execution and shows me where the execution was going to occur*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebug (FF add-on)
Open Firebug (press F12), Open Script tab and use search field.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In chrome (> v 15) developer tools you can search all sources.

Press F12, make sure the console is shown, then on the tab bar next to console is search, go into that tab, type in function Bar  and hit return.  Or after pressing F12 press Shift Ctrl F (Command option F on Mac)

There are a few caveats on this , e.g. i dont think this will find scripts inside iframes